# Why do we use function symbol instead of defining it in terms of predicates?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, foundations

Set theory defines function as a kind of relations/predicates. If so, then why we introduce function symbol instead of introducing $n$-ary function as a $(n+1)$-ary predicate symbol?

Comment: Convention, convenience. We don't really want to talk about the unique $y$ so that $(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y)\in f$ when we can use the much shorter $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

Comment: We are accustomed to think at "operations" as *functions* : $+(n,m)$ as the sum of $n$ and $m$, and so on.

Comment: It would just make it hard to write $y=f(g(h(x)))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the "functional way" is easier to teach and hard to get rid of later (and not necessary enough). Most people feel well with a function being a "machine" or "process", something goes in and something else comes out. This is how it appears in reality, e.g. when using a calculator. We not really relate the input and the output to each other.

Like many other set theoretic constructions, this should probably just be seen as a foundational thing. Or would you say that you see

- natural numbers as specific finite sets,
- whole numbers as (equivalence classes of) pairs of natural numbers,
- real numbers as sets of Cauchy sequences?

In the end, what is important is the concept of what a function is instead of how it is constructed in the *currently most used foundational system*. There are other ways do build math, e.g. Category theory. And if you want to build a function in there, you better know what the idea of a function is and not what its specific construction is in any other foundational system.

However, that the specific notation $f(x)=y$ is seen as "better" as $(x,y)\in f$ is purely educational to some degree. In the end, also the latter notation can describe a mapping process. I just think that the first way better communicates the distinction between $x$ and $y$ and that everywhere $f(x)$ can be substituted by $y$.

Comment: "whole numbers as pairs of natural numbers"? Of course not, I view them as *equivalence classes* of pairs of natural numbers ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen My bad ;) Changed it. There are other minor inaccuracies, but I hope the idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different possible answers to this question.

For start one could argue that there are different foundational systems, as Martin Löf type theory, which has functions as a primitive notion (as opposed to a defined one).

Another possible reason, a little more technical, is that having function symbols allows to build term models which is one of the common technique in model theory for building up models for theories.

Still a technical answer: adding function symbols is a nice way to extend the theory in such a way that we have quantifier elimination, a nice property of theories that comes in handy for proving stuff like completeness and other properties of a theory.

These are just few reason why having function symbols is important, I believe other with more knowledge than me in logic and specifically in model theory can give you many more interesting reasons.